# How to put a fragment on top of other fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two fragments. I want one to be on top of the other with semi transparent background. [image: The first fragment] and [image: The fragment that i want on top] and this is the result that i want [image: result picture]. How can i do that with kotlin?

Comment: That's basically a ``Dialog``, so you probably want a ``DialogFragment``: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#DialogFragment It'll appear over everything else and give you the scrim (the blurred/darkened background) for free

Comment: Ah nice i didn't know that DialogFragment have the basic fragment lifecycle methods. Thanks

Comment: Only thing to be aware of is DialogFragments don't call ``onCreateView``, so they don't create a ``viewLifecycleOwner`` - if you need to use that, you're supposed to pass the DialogFragment itself instead: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs#lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use this one https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Don’t use the old support library. Use Jetpack.